# popup position changing if scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup div, which is show on click of a an image, i want to show the div on the clicked place. Now that works only if the page is in default position, that is not scrolled or not zoomed. if scrolled or zoomed then the position of popup is changing.

The normal popup

[image]

thats ok.

Now when i scroll the page down and click on tht gear image(settings). its like this.

[image]

please see tht page is scrolled and the problem. The other on is when i zoom it. If zoomed in its like:

[image]

my js is:

```
$('.settings img').live('click', function (event) {
            $('.set_pop').css('left',event.pageX);     
            $('.set_pop').css('top',event.pageY);
            $('.set_pop').css('display','inline');     
            $(".set_pop").css("position", "fixed");  
            $(".set_pop").show();
        });
```

my css: and the blue(header) its position is fixed

```
.settings{
                float:right;
                margin-right: 3%;
                border: none;
                margin-top: 5px;
                cursor: pointer;

            }
            .set_pop{
                position:absolute;
                margin-right: 50px;
                margin-top:10px;
                width:100px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
                -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
                box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
                border-radius:5px;
                -moz-border-radius:5px;
                -webkit-border-radius:5px;
                z-index:10;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                color:#000;
            }
```

**html**

```
<div class="settings">
             <img src="images/setting.png" alt="settings" width="30px" height="30px"/>
               <div class="set_pop">
                   <ul class="strip">
                       <li onclick="location.href='register'">Manage Users</li>
                   <li>test</li>
                   <li>test</li>
                   <li>test</li>
                   </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
```

sorry for posting everything, actually i am nt able to get the problem, i tried various scripts and changing all the positions. Someone here could help me out, i hope.

Thanks & regards

Comment: try using the css elements `top` and `right` to position the popup instead of `margin`. further more i would suggest using `position:relative` and put the dropdown in/after the button (and just hide it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your class to this :

```
.set_pop {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #666666;
color: #000000;
margin-right: 50px;
margin-top: 10px;
position: fixed;
width: 100px;
z-index: 10;
top: 40px;
z-index: 10;
```

}

What i did is, i changed the **position: absolute;** to **position: fixed;** and added "top" and "right" to position it correctly. You can change the top/right accordingly.

- Absolute is displayed relative to the document (OR if inside another
  element is relative to that element as long as it is not static)
- Relative is relative to the document but can be positioned using the
  top bottom left & right properties and scrolls with the page
- Fixed is displayed fixed to the browser window and therefore doesn't
  scroll but moves if your resize the window

[For detailed explanation, click here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Comment: damn, what a foll i am, actually that script was overwriting my css. i removed it and its perfect. thankyou boss